# Can't create an Azure project

Tags: visual-studio, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm following a tutorial on Xamarin right now. In the tutorial they create an Azure Mobile App project for the backend. But the pop-up is empty for me and I can only see the layout. Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

This is the screen I get:
[image: This is the screen I get.]

Comment: double check your VS installation whether you have asp.net and azure stuff installed. possible repair the installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the pop-up is empty for me and I can only see the layout. Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

In my local machine, I installed both VS2015 and VS2017. I have reproduced the issue.

In my VS2017, I could create the azure mobile app as below:

[image]

But in VS2015, I couldn't do it as your image shows. I suggest you could firstly report this issue as below image shows.

[image]

Since I don't know your machine environment, so I suggest you could try below two workaround.

One is you could use VS2017 which you could download it from this [url](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and 
select installing azure and xamarin.

Second you could directly download the backend in the azure portal.

1.Open your portal and click quick start.

[image]

2.Select Xamarin forms

[image]

3.Download the backend:

[image]